# Strings of malicious code to look for after a hack

Tags: hacked

It's always a struggle to find which files have been created or compromised after a Wordpress has been hacked, so I've created [a PHP script](https://pastebin.com/Ttbmfuaf) that scans in every files' source code on the serverand looks for the presence of suspicious strings, which are the following:

- gzinflate
- $_REQUEST[$_GET
- fwrite
- file_get_contents

Can you think of any other strings that are often present in malicious code, and specific to them, that I could look for?

Comment: There are already many tools that do this sort of thing. Trying to do it yourself just means you’re extremely likely to miss something.

Comment: Maybe I'm looking for the wrong keywords because English isn't my native language, but I can't find any tools that seems both efficient and legit.